# Configure F5 load balancer for LDAP

Tags: ldap, load-balancing, f5

We care currently running LDAP as a Master-Master configuration with one primary.  We are supplying the Spring LdapContextSource with two LDAP nodes to use as primary/failover.

We went to this configuration because previously our LDAP had been behind an f5 load balancer, but we would run into replication issues when a user was created on Node A, but the f5 sent the updates to Node B before the two could sync.

However, now we are running into a situation where we are over-utilizing one node. And ignoring the second node.

What I would like to be able to do is configure the f5 such that all Create, Update, Delete operations went to a primary node, but reads were distributed between the two LDAP Nodes.

Any thoughts on how to configure the f5 to achieve this?

For reference we are using a 389-ds implementation of LDAP.

Comment: If we've answered your question please mark it as such so that it will help others; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation: Split the work into two separate VIPs if possible. At least that's what we've done with mysql here — a write VIP and a read-only VIP. I know this question is for LDAP, but LDAP is a type of database, and your needs are very similar to mysql read/write dilemmas.

Write VIP: Set up your F5 pool with Priority Group Activation set to "Less than 1" on the Members tab. This is a failover configuration and does not split load since the LDAP sync isn't fast enough to support it. The higher priority number takes the traffic first. If it goes down, traffic flows to the lower priority. You assign priority as you are adding each node.

Read VIP: Load-balance traffic with a typical configuration as you had it before.

In both VIPs, of course you need a valid LDAP query in your health monitor that proves the service is working correctly. If allowed by your directory, you don't even have to login. You can just read the directory, searching for a particular base and filter defining an object within that base. This makes the health monitor faster and less troublesome while remaining effective. LDAP login in F5 monitors can be a major pain, so it's nice to skip it when feasible.